# Unable to Run SQL Script from within SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I'm trying to setup my Windows machine to be able to do a udemy course on Oracle SQL. I have the docker Oracle Express database container running locally on my machine. I plan on using the Datagrip IDE to run the queries and I am trying to execute the Sample Schema scripts that include the HR Schema as well as some other schemas. The problem I am running into is that the scripts are trying to reference some scripts located in a subfolder within the same folder as the mksample script. And I am getting an error message saying that it is unable to open the script in the subfolder of the folder that has the mksample script.

I attempted to run the scripts from inside the container using SQLPlus and got the following output from the terminal.

```
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/human_resources/hr_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/product_media/pm_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/info_exchange/ix_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/sh_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/bus_intelligence/bi_main.sql"
Connected.
not spooling currently
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/mkverify.sql"
```

The folder looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gua8k.png)

Comment: well does that    folder path exist?

Comment: when the mksample script runs it calls several scripts located in subfolders of the folder that mksample is in does that answer your question

Comment: The initial script I am trying to run is mksample

Comment: If the initial script in turn calls other scripts, then all of those subfolders and scripts must also exist. Oracle often uses a top-level orchestration script to execute a series of installation sub-scripts in the correct order, with correct settings, automatically.